# Android full screen dialog fragment like calendar app

Tags: android, material-design, android-dialogfragment, android-statusbar

I am trying to achieve a full-screen dialog like the below image. I am able to show a full screen dialog but when the dialog is shown the status bar color changes to black and does not keep the primary-dark color.

Heres my dialog fragment

```
public class IconsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout to use as dialog or embedded fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_icons_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final RelativeLayout root = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        root.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        // creating the fullscreen dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setContentView(root);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
        dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogAnimation);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use Dialog in full screen? Use a simple Activity..

Answer (score 0):

To get DialogFragment on full screen

Override onStart of your DialogFragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

In order to setStatusBarColor you need to set the flag: FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS

```
public void setStatusBarColorIfPossible(int color) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
   getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
   }
}
```

Comment: where to call this method?

Answer (score -2):

One way is to change back your status bar color as theme programmatically whenever you open the dialog.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Your theme color);
```

}

Comment: This isn´t what was asked. Here you can find what the he wanted: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/showing-material-design-dialogs-in-an-android-app--cms-30013